# Change plotted data in a figure when x_range of another figure linked to the other one is changed in Bokeh

Tags: python, callback, bokeh

I have two figures in which data source is linked in Bokeh. The left figure show (x, y) and the right figure shows (v, z) and the other shows (x, y).  I want to re-draw the left figure when the x_range of the right figure is changed so that the data points not shown in the right panel are removed from the left panel. I thought I should use a callback feature of Bokeh, but I'm not familiar with it.  I tried to write the following code, but it does not work. It would be great if someone tell me how to do it.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, save, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.formatters import DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.palettes import brewer, all_palettes, viridis
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import WMTSTileSource
from bokeh.layouts import column, row, gridplot

x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)
z = x**2
v = np.exp(-0.5 * x**2)
colors = np.array(viridis(x.size))

source_all = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(x=x,
              y=y,
              z=z,
              v=v,
              colors=colors,
              index=np.arange(x.size, dtype=np.int)))

source_plot = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(x=x,
              y=y,
              z=z,
              v=v,
              colors=colors))

left = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300, title=None, 
              x_range=(-3, 3),
              y_range=(-3, 3),
             tools=['reset', 'save', 'pan', 'wheel_zoom', 'tap', 'box_select'])
left.circle('x', 'y', source=source_plot, color='colors')

right = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300, title=None, # x_range=(),
              tools=['reset', 'save', 'pan', 'wheel_zoom', 'tap', 'box_select'])
right.circle('v', 'z', source=source_plot, color='colors')

def callback(left=left, right=right, source=source_plot, source_all=source_all, window=None):

    x_range = right.x_range
    x_range.have_updated_interactively = False

    xmin = x_range[0]
    xmax = x_range[1]

    data = source.data
    data_all = source_all.data

    x, y, z, v, color = data['x'], data['y'], data['z'], data['v'], data['colors']
    xa, ya, za, va, colora = data_all['x'], data_all['y'], data_all['z'], data_all['v'], data_all['colors']

    for i in range(len(v)):
        if v[i] < xmin or v[i] > xmax:
            x[i] = np.nan
            y[i] = np.nan
            z[i] = np.nan
            color[i] = None
        else:
            x[i] = xa[i]
            y[i] = ya[i]
            z[i] = za[i]
            color[i] = colora[i]
    Bokeh.index[left.id].plot_canvas_view.update_dataranges()
    source.change.emit()

callback = CustomJS.from_py_func(callback)


right.x_range.js_on_change('start', callback)

p = gridplot([[left, right]])

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work that with a callback but isn't a lasso_select or box_select doing more or less what you want?
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have tried it and found it can be an alternative, though it's not perfectly good for what I want to achieve.  I'm collecting a time series data and the time baseline can be very long (x-axis in the right panel) at some point with a lot of data points overlapping in the left panel, so I want to show only those appeared in the right panel rather than highlighting them.